# Adding forces to body post-finalize?

Tags: drake

I'm setting up a simple simulation where I want a body (a box) to fall in a gravity field for half a second and then rise up due to a force I apply on it which overcomes gravity.

I've tried implementing this force using three methods, using `AddInForce`, `AddInForceInWorld`, and `AddForceElement`. Since this is called while the simulation is running, `AddForceElement` threw an error as expected. With the other two, though, no errors or warnings were thrown, yet the box clearly does not have a new force acting on it.

I've checked for a new force element with `num_force_elements()` too but none are added.

Here is my loop for timing this event:

```cpp
    while( current_time < FLAGS_duration && !terminate){
        if (current_time > 0.5 && !forced) {

            std::cout << "\nAdding Force of type " << FLAGS_box_f << " at 0.5 seconds...\n";

            // Add Rising Force to box
            auto forces = drake::multibody::MultibodyForces<double>(plant);
            drake::multibody::SpatialForce<double> forceup(Vector3d::Zero(), Vector3d(0, 0, 100));

            if (FLAGS_box_f == "spring") {
                plant.AddForceElement<LinearSpringDamper>(
                    plant.GetBodyByName("Box"), Vector3d::Zero(),
                    plant.world_body(), Vector3d(0, 0, 1),
                    0., 10., 1.);

            } else if (FLAGS_box_f == "world") {
                plant.GetBodyByName("Box").AddInForceInWorld(
                    plant_context,
                    forceup,
                    &forces);

            } else {
                plant.GetBodyByName("Box").AddInForce(
                    plant_context,
                    Vector3d::Zero(),
                    forceup,
                    plant.GetBodyByName("Box").body_frame(),
                    &forces);
            }

            plant.CalcForceElementsContribution(plant_context, &forces);
            std::cout << "Plant: " << plant.num_force_elements() << " force_elements\n";
            forced = true;
        }

        simulator.StepTo(current_time + time_delta);
        current_time = simulator_context.get_time();
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm going through the motions right, and also still don't understand very well the MultibodyForces object I am storing the forces in the calls to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Joaquin Giraldo,

The way to add external forces to your model is with an input force. Everything in Drake are input/output ports. In this case, you must use `MultibodyPlant::get_applied_spatial_force_input_port()`.
See the file `multibody/plant/test/externally_applied_spatial_force_test.cc` for an example on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note: what you need is a force element that is *always* present, but varies its force output based on time. None of the built-in ones behave that way, so you will have to write one.

Comment: gotcha! I'll look into doing something like this

Comment: working on this - it seems like calls to addinforce need to be made pre-finalize, correct? how is that possible when it requires a context to be added? I'm not sure when is the right time to call this

Comment: no need for a force element in this case. Please see my answer using an input port

Comment: That does seem easier!