# Up-to-date workflow for adding external forces to object post-finalized for trajectory optimization

Tags: drake

<s>I am struggling to add an external wrench to a gripper. In my case, I have a floating hand trying to push an object. I would like a spatial wrench applied to the gripper's CoM as part of my decision variable.</s>

Referring to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271126/applying-an-external-force-to-an-object-in-pydrake), it looks like things have moved on. One of the instantiation `VectorExternallyAppliedSpatialForced()` is deprecated.

I tried to look for the doc. `ExternallyAppliedSpatialForceMultiplexer()` seems to be a close one. Then I tried similarly of using a `System` to output a force:

```
force_object.body_index = plant.GetBodyIndices(hand_model_index).pop()
force_object.F_Bq_W = SpatialForce(tau=np.zeros(3), f=np.array([0., 0., 10.]))

# a way to put force object into the AbstractValue???

forces = ExternallyAppliedSpatialForceMultiplexer(1)
value = AbstractValue.Make(forces)
force_system = builder.AddSystem(ConstantValueSource(value))
builder.Connect(force_system.get_output_port(0), plant.get_applied_spatial_force_input_port())
```

Is there an update workflow for this purpose? <s>I am using AutoDiff and having the input wrench as decision variables at all time points. What is the best way to set/update the wrench for trajectory optimization.</s>

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for not thinking this through. The updated question is: if there is an updated version for [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271126/applying-an-external-force-to-an-object-in-pydrake). It really does not matter for trajectory optimization as I could just have JT@Fext to the manipulator equation! was a bit silly to ask!

Comment: JT@Fext if not on the CoM,  or just selection_mat * Fext that directly corresponds to the dofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to put a constant external force into the multibody plant input port, you can do e.g.

```
force = ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce()
force.body_index = plant.GetBodyByName(f"box_0_0_1").index()
force.F_Bq_W = SpatialForce(tau=[0, 0, 0], f=[0, 0, 0])
forces = builder.AddSystem(ConstantValueSource(Value([force])))
builder.Connect(forces.get_output_port(), plant.get_applied_spatial_force_input_port())
```

If you do want to put an `ExternallyAppliedSpatialForceMultiplexer` in the middle (it's not needed for this application, but perhaps it helps in a more complicated case), that would look like e.g.:

```
force = ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce()
force.body_index = plant.GetBodyByName(f"box_0_0_1").index()
force.F_Bq_W = SpatialForce(tau=[0, 0, 0], f=[0, 0, 0])
forces = builder.AddSystem(ConstantValueSource(Value([force])))
                                 
forces_mux = builder.AddSystem(ExternallyAppliedSpatialForceMultiplexer(1))
builder.Connect(forces.get_output_port(), forces_mux.get_input_port(0))
builder.Connect(forces_mux.get_output_port(), plant.get_applied_spatial_force_input_port())
```

Comment: Just tried it! Thanks a lot!